# placing a 2 divs over an existing website?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to place two divs over the top of an existing website, as in this image:

[image]

I can do this fine in firefox/google chrome etc, but it doesn't seem to work in IE.

Could someone point me to a simple example of how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227485/fake-lightbox-in-ie-easy-html-css-fix-for-someone

Comment: Thanks @AndreasWinter - that is my previous post. I have it working to a degree, but in IE the shadow layer, won't fill the whole of the page if you scroll down. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Not even with the fix I gave you in the previous post? (see my comments and now the answers here :D)

Comment: no @AndreasWinter if you extend the white_content box's height the black shadow box below does not also extend :(

Comment: ahh okay, yes, cause they are both `position: absolute` and the inner box don't expand the outer box. So you need to change height with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the following code in your head and change `position:absolute` back to `position:fixed` in your css

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .black_overlay {
            position:absolute;
            top: expression(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat" ? document.documentElement.scrollTop+"px" : body.scrollTop+"px");
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to really emphasize using z-index.

Z-Index is like applying layers to your HTML, in which case you may have a layer on top, in the middle, and on the bottom. Hence 3 divs positioned like layers.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I can get the divs to float above each other, but now the problem is with the shadow layer not filling the whole page when you scroll down. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5V288/8/

Answer (score 0):

Here I updated the css. Instead of `position:absolute;` I used `fixed` so that is doesn't move with scrolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/5V288/9/

Comment: Which version? I just tested IE8 & IE7. They both seemed fine.